# Access Paginator object in controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5, paginator

I am using `cakePHP 2.5` and I want to access `$this->Paginator->hasNext()` in controller, but it through exception.

```
    $type = array('featured', 'newest', 'trending');

    foreach($type as $each)
    {
        $conditions = array('Product.status'=>'1', "is_$each" => '1');
        $this->Product->recursive = 1;

        //retrieve and set final result set
        $this->paginate = array(
                                'fields' => array('Product.*'),
                                'conditions' => $conditions,
                                'limit' => $page_limit,
                                'page' => $page,
                                'order' => "$order_by $order_by_sort",
                            );
        $products[$each] = $this->paginate('Product');
    }
```

On my page, I want to display 3 type of product `featured/trending/newest`. Initially I load first page by default, then when user scroll down then I will call ajax and append next page like wise. But if last page is reached then I want to stop ajax call (because unknown page through `404 not found error`).

To overcome that, I prevent AJAX call for unknown pages. And also make sure that first page isn't last!!

Hope my details make sense!

I could not find any answer on any forum/document. Please guide me or point me if it's duplicate of any.

Comment: The call/need for `hasNext` is still missing from the question - I've written you an answer anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and cannot*) access a helper in the controller.

Take a look at [the source code for hasNext](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php#L561-L570) which is just calling [the helper function _hasPage](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php#L589-L599), which is simply checking the parameters array.

The paginator parameters are [all available in the controller](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php#L218-L229):

```
$paging = array(
    'page' => $page,
    'current' => count($results),
    'count' => $count,
    'prevPage' => ($page > 1),
    'nextPage' => ($count > ($page * $limit)),
    'pageCount' => $pageCount,
    'order' => $order,
    'limit' => $limit,
    'options' => Hash::diff($options, $defaults),
    'paramType' => $options['paramType']
);
```

So from the code in the question:

```
 $this->request['paging']['Product']['nextPage']
```

Is the information you're looking for (it will be overwritten each time you call `paginate`.

### Consider your application design.

Unless you have exactly the same number of featured, newest and trending records - it'd be better to have one ajax request for each type. Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541974/dashboard-timeline/15548716), for more information on implementing infinite-scroll type pages.

** Almost anything is possible, you certainly should not need to use a helper in a controller though*.

Comment: This will introduce view related logic into the controller, which is IMHO wrong. The check can be made very easy in the view where the requests for the next page happen by passing the state of the pagination back to the client inside the response.

Comment: @burzum "view related logic into the controller" is a _huge_ stretch when the view logic reads parameters which are set and freely available in the controller.

Comment: @burzum & AD, Thanks both of you I don't know my architecture is wrong or not, but yes `$this->request['paging']['Product']['nextPage']` leads me to solution. Also every problem can be solved by multiple ways and probably my way is wrong as per others' perspective, and vice-versa. But goal is to solve problem!!! :)

Answer (score -1):

#### MVC Violation

> $this->Paginator->hasNext()

That's a method of the **helper**. Helpers are **not** thought to be used in controllers because this is a violation of the MVC pattern and **bad practice**. If you *think* you have to you're wrong: Fix your architecture, it's broken by design.

#### Proper solution

Return the status of the pagination along with the data in the AJAX response:

```
$this->set('pagination', $this->request->paging['Product']);
$this->set('products', $result);
$this->set('_serialize', ['products', 'pagination']);
```

You can change the state of your view depending on the data then:

```
if (pagination.Product.nextPage == true) { /*... */ }
```

Comment: I can use that in view, but I am calling `paginate` in a loop within controller. So can not get value `hasNext()` for each loop in view.

Comment: Did you actually read and *understood* what I wrote? **That's wrong!**

Comment: @burzum Can you please tone it down and **try not to be aggressive towards people on stack overflow**. You're hard to ignore where over half your posts are you shouting at people.

Comment: I'm not aggressive nor do I "shout" which is for me wring with capslock on. I'm actually a pretty calm person but I don't like to spoon-feed people who don't read and to be fancy in my expressions and usually say what I think pretty directly. As long as this is voluntarily done I don't feel an urgent need to add candy to my "reports". Deal with it.

Comment: "you're wrong" "Fix your architecture" "Did you actually read and understood what I wrote?" "That's wrong!" - These are all pretty agressive/accusative statements and your answers typically always include at least one attack on the author or their code/choices. Here's a challenge: put the word "please" in **every post your write** for the rest of the month, it should help you be [more of an elbow](https://twitter.com/AD7six/status/651401007080046594).

Comment: As far as I know you I think you're smart enough to realize that each of the statements is right. It's not an attack as long as it's technical and not personal. If you like to pad him, go for it, write an exhaustive answer why using a helper in a controller is wrong. Thanks for the downvote, I'll return the favour in time.

Comment: @AD7six  Calm down guys!! Let me put some of my code to realize what I need.

Comment: @Parixit sorry, you're just the latest victim, as I see it. The downvote is because of the unchanged tone of the post - I vote on all posts objectively, I gave you an opportunty to correct it which you rejected. Whilst you understand how to use CakePHP what you don't seem to understand, is that when answering a question you're providing answers to future readers. Who wants to google a problem, find a question and read a tyrannical rant about why the OP is wrong? They want an answer to a problem (which in this case hasn't been clarified yet). </end>

Comment: I understand that very well, but there is no better answer for a vague question like that. It is obviously wrong what he's doing architecture wise (calling helper in controller) but I can't mind read...